# Get count of documents matching different conditions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collection: bookSchema as:

```
[
    {
      _id: ObjectId("637d05dc32428ed75ea08d09"),
      book_details: {
        book_name: "random123",
        book_auth: "Amber"
      }
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("637d0673ce0f17f6c473dee2"),
      book_details: {
        book_name: "random321",
        book_auth: "Amber"
      }
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("637d069a3d597c8458ebe4ec"),
      book_details: {
        book_name: "random676",
        book_auth: "Amber"
      }
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("637d06c05b32d503007bcb54"),
      book_details: {
        book_name: "random999",
        book_auth: "Saurav"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Desired O/P to show as:

```
{
  score_ambr: 3,
  score_saurabh: 1
}
```

For this I tried as:

```
db.bookSchema.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$eq": [
          "$book_details.book_auth",
          "Amber"
        ]
      },
      "score_ambr": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    },

  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$eq": [
          "$book_details.book_auth",
          "Saurav"
        ]
      },
      "score_saurabh": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    },

  }
])
```

I tried using $group to as I want to group all the matching documents in one and use $count to give the number of count for the matching documents but it doesn't seem to be working and gives the O/P as

O/P:

```
[
  {
    "_id": false,
    "score_sau": 2
  }
]
```

MongoDB Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cZ64KwAmwlv

Comment: what does  3 and 1 mean and do you always hardcode the query with score_sau and score_abr

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is two group twice and create a dynamic key from the `book_details.book_auth`:

```
db.bookSchema.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$book_details.book_auth", count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0, 
      data: {$push: {
          k: {$concat: ["score_", {$toLower: "$_id"}]},
          v: {$sum: "$count"}
      }}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mi0ezy94J9K)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what mean `3` and `1` in your example but if I've understood correctly you can try this query:

The trick here is to use [$facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to create "two ways" in the aggregation. One option will filter by `Amber` and the other one by `Saurav`.

And then, as values are filtered, you only need yo know the size of the array generated.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "score_ambr": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "book_details.book_auth": "Amber"
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_saurabh": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "book_details.book_auth": "Saurav"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "score_ambr": {
        "$size": "$score_ambr"
      },
      "score_saurabh": {
        "$size": "$score_saurabh"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dItgJD2HTxG)

Note that in this way you avoid to use `$group`.